# How to return difference of two objects

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program where I need to compare two db objects and return the difference.

The objects look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"),
    "contact" : {
        "firstName" : "Mark",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
        "parentsBloodType" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AB+",
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "A+",
            }, 
        ],
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-31T07:13:11.278Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:59:41.611Z") 
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a24"),
    "contact" : {
        "firstName" : "David",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
        "parentsBloodType" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "B+",
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "A+",
            }, 
        ],
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-31T07:13:12.278Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:59:42.611Z") 
}
```

The format of the result is not important, as long as it tells me that the name and one of the blood types is different and the value (could be string or HashMap).

I tried to convert it to a string, split the string into a HashMap and compare keys and values, but the splitting of the string did not go well because of the arrays inside the object.

Is it possible to compare two objects directly?

Comment: The two objects that you are talking about are Java objects, right? They're not literally the strings you showed here, right? What you showed here is just a representation, right?

Comment: If possible, I would reformat this data to be valid JSON (it is almost) and then use one of the many very good JSON libraries to have this mapped to Java classes, like GSON does. Then you can easily access all data as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can compare an arraylist using **contains** function and by overriding equals method in your pojo.
So write in your main class

yourlistarray.conatins(pojo) //will return true or false

and in your pojo class use below code according to your parameters(in your case name)

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getName());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object object) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            Pojo rsp = (Pojo) object;
            if (this.Name.equals(rsp.getName())) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: You have a valid JSON like the below one:

```
{
    "_id": "5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23",
    "contact": {
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "parentsBloodType": [{
                "type": "AB+"
            },
            {
                "type": "A+"
            }
        ]
    },
    "createdAt": "2019-10-31T07:13:11.278Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-11-26T09:59:41.611Z"
}
```

You may create Java objects that is according to json schema. That may look something like here.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("contact")
    private Contact contact;
    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    private String createdAt;
    @JsonProperty("updatedAt")
    private String updatedAt;

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contact")
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contact")
    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updatedAt")
    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    @JsonProperty("updatedAt")
    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Contact {

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("parentsBloodType")
    private List<ParentsBloodType> parentsBloodType = null;

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("parentsBloodType")
    public List<ParentsBloodType> getParentsBloodType() {
        return parentsBloodType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("parentsBloodType")
    public void setParentsBloodType(List<ParentsBloodType> parentsBloodType) {
        this.parentsBloodType = parentsBloodType;
    }

}
```

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ParentsBloodType {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Now you override the hashcode and equals methods for these classes. And then you would be able to filter out the records based on the key/s that you want to.

Answer (score 0):

These objects seem to be coming from mongo db.
So the best way would be calling the mongo from java directly and converting the objects to the java objects, then implement equals as its usually done in java, or use Comparator if you wish to compare the objects with your custom logic.

If its impossible and its your input (like your program reads these files as an input), then you can:

1. Clean up the Strings (replace the line with ObjectId  which is mongo specific stuff with `_id` : "5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23" (for the first object) and replace the ISODate wit h the actual date if you need it for comparison or remove the line altogether.
   Technically you can do that with regular expressions.
2. Create a Java Object that should represent one document (constructors, getters, setters are omitted for brevity):

```
public class MYObject {
    private String _id;
    private Contact contact;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt, updatedAt;
}

public class Contact {
  String firstName, lastName;
  List<ParentsBloodType> parentsBloodTypes;
}

public class ParentBloodType {
    private String type;
}
```

3. Use libraries like Jackson or GSon to convert the result of step "1" to Objects of type "MyObject" - they can do that automatically as long as step 1 produces a proper JSON.
4. Implement equals in the hierarchy of object you've created during step "2" and compare